# Replace initial page with new page including new JS calls. mobile app/phonegap build

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Phonegap build has a glitch, the compiled apps load a splash page then the splash page closes before the dom has completely loaded. They are currently working on the issue, but i figure if I can figure out how to load an initial index page to show the user a please wait message or the like, then while they are looking at that I can load the real initial page including loading all the JS files etc. Can this be done? Because right now it looks as though JQuery mobile loads the new page into the waiting page's dom, therefore not loading the JS files.

Answer (score 0):

First, can you work around the issue with AutoHideSplashScreen? Without that, phonegap tends to hide the splash screen too early anyway.

Adding a loading page can be useful sometimes - simply call `$.mobile.changePage("start.html")` when you are done loading stuff.

Any script references your main page needs will have to be in the head section of the loading page though - the head section of ajax loaded pages is always ignored. Scripts in the body of the second page will work also, but you are likely to run into some side effects with that approach.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was afraid of.